# What strategy do you use to earn the Blitzkrieg achievement during the Media Blitz mission?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

To earn the Blitzkrieg achievement in StarCraft 2 you are supposed to complete the Media Blitz mission in under 20 minutes on hard. I keep coming in right at 21 minutes. Not sure what's wrong with my strategy but I can't quite crack 20.

What strategy have you devised to earn the achievement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a helpful link with a full description:

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Campaign/Media_Blitz

Strategy summarized from the above link:

> During the surprise attack, start
> with the mech-base destroying all
> siege tanks and factories. Use the
> remaining time to destroy as much of
> the starport base as possible.
>
> After the surprise attack, immediately send
> the Odin, initial Thor, and 2 repair
> SCVs to attack the 2 bases closest to
> your own base. Concurrently, produce
> two more Thors and an armory to
> research vehicle upgrades.
>
> Right after the two small bases are destroyed,
> take out the starport base, the mech
> base, and finally the infantry base.
>
> Continue to produce & deploy Thors and
> repair SCVs throughout the mission.

Comment: The strategy from that link totally worked but it'd be good to summarize the link. This discussion on meta.stackoverflow explains why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13369/is-it-okay-to-answer-a-stackoverflow-question-with-a-link/13370#13370

Comment: oh sorry, ill keep that in mind next time :) i just wanted to give the link here to avoid spoilers(well mostly because i haven't played through that part yet myself so i didn't want to spoil myself)

Answer (score 1):

Send out the odin and initial thor with a repairing scv to wipe out two bases (assuming you went for the mech base first). Start two engineering bays and research infantry upgrades asap. I started with air base and took the early expo. You do not want to build units early on, because you need the minerals for your economy.

Keep grabing expos, slowly building up your infantry army, while not forgetting the upgrades, and start capturing first tower at around 12 minute mark. Turn your CC into planetary fortress if you are having trouble defending might bot be a bad idea. Keep adding on barracks and training more units and hopefully you can finish on-time.